# GET json data with jquery ajax call to nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I am sending data using Nodejs res.end() in JSON format, and I am also setting headers as application/json and but I am not getting the data in the success function of jquery ajax call, instead I am getting the data directly in JSON format, but I want it to come in the success function of jquery ajax call as I have to display them in datatable. I even tried res.render() and res.send() but not able to get it. please help!!

**Nodejs code**

```js
router.get('/user_list',(req,res,next)=>{
   let new_password = generator.generate({
        length: 16,
        numbers: true,
        symbols: true,
        uppercase: true,
        strict: true,
        exclude: ["(",")","[","]",":","-",",","{","}","<",">",".","^","/"]
      });
  connection.query("update user, client set user.status = client.status where user.client_id = client.id",(error,result)=>{
    if(error){
      console.log(error);
    }else{
      connection.query('select user.username,user.email,user.msg_id,user.status,system.name from user inner join system on user.system_id = system.id; select id, name from client;',(error,result)=>{
        if(error){
          console.log(error);
        }else{
          let value = {values: result,new_password};
          //res.json(value);
         // res.render('user_list', {user_data: value});
          res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });res.end(JSON.stringify(value));
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

**JQuery Code**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url:'user_list',
        type:'GET',
        //dataSrc: 'user_list',
        datatype:'json',
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
          $('#example').dataTable({
            data:data,
            columns: [
              {data:'values[0][1].username'},
              {data:'values[0][1].name'},
              {data:'values[0][1].email'},
              {data:'values[0][1].msg_id'},
            ]
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: 1. NEVER EVER post code as image for obvious reasons 2. just use `res.send(some_object)` and express will set the header appropriately 3. `but i am not getting the data in the success function of jquery ajax call, instead i am getting the data directly in json format` what? those are two unrelated things.

Comment: i tried res.send() but i am not able to get the response in success function of jquery ajax call.@ChrisG

Comment: Any errors in the console? Note that since this is a GET request and you don't have any parameters, you can simply go to `localhost:3000/user_list` in the browser and you should see the JSON. Does that work? Also, please edit your question so it contains the actual code, or this question will likely get closed.

Comment: There is no error in console and also i get the response that way in the browser but i don't want that, i want it in the success function so that i populate the data in datatable.@ChrisG

Comment: But you ARE getting it in the success function. `console.log(data)` is *inside* the success function! I'm starting to think that this has *nothing* to do with ajax and is just about the `.dataTable()` call. When the data is logged in the console, is it just a long String?

Comment: it doesn't print anything in the browser's console, it just gives me as rest api response example: http://www.gregreda.com/images/scraping-api-response.png

Comment: Just to make sure... you DO have a `router.get('/', ...` set up somewhere in your code, right? You are using express I assume, so you do have a view engine set up and are rendering templates? And there's an index page that includes the jQuery code? Let's put it this way: what happens when you go to http://localhost:8080 ?

Comment: yeah everything you mentioned is in place and when i hit localhost:8080 it goes to my login page.

Comment: So on which page did you include the ajax/getJSON request...? Note that I'm rapidly running out of patience, given what a basic issue this is, how long it takes to deal with this and communicating with you is like pulling teeth. No offense.

Comment: I have a seperate html file for showing the user list and i have written the jquery code in seperate file which i am importing in that html file using <script src=""></script>.

Comment: Ok, so what happens when you visit this page? Does my jQuery code log the user list to the console or not?

Comment: Thanks for all your response and also sorry for the trouble actually i didn't check before that my friend was using the same route to render the html and making the ajax call, so changing the route solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this so we can narrow down the problem:

```
router.get('/user_list', function (req, res) {
    const list = [
        { id: 0, name: "Alice"},
        { id: 1, name: "Bob"}
    ];
    res.send(list);
});
```

In your index/script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('user_list').then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    });
});
```

This should display the Array in the console.

Comment: I commented everything and just used your code but still getting the response in the browser and this also didn't print anything in the console. Screenshot of the response :https://imgur.com/a/Lqp9JoF

Comment: Ok, so now go to the page that contains the jQuery code (`$.getJSON`) and check the browser console. (also, seeing just the JSON is obviously what's supposed to happen when you visit `/user_list` via the address bar... ; we're troubleshooting your code and have just successfully excluded the backend as the source of the problem)

Comment: i already posted an url in above comment which contains the screen shot of the ouput. If that's how its supposed to work then how am i supposed to make an ajax call and get the data in front end and display it?

Comment: That was only to check whether the backend works as it should. The next step is to make the same request via AJAX.

Comment: yeah at first when i posted the question i was making an ajax call to backend and receiving the data in the browser and not in the success function.